# Disappearing data with stat_contour in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a series of contour plots in `ggplot2` using `stat_contour`.  I have noticed that when my z-value has a very small range across the dataset, my plot will be missing portions of the data.  Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(R = rep(1:16, 2), C = c(rep(1, 16), rep(2, 16)),
                   V = c(25.00750, 25.00700, 25.00646, 25.00585, 25.00518,
                         25.00444, 25.00362, 25.00272, 25.00171, 25.00061,
                         24.99938, 24.99802, 24.99652, 24.99486, 24.99303,
                         24.99100, 25.00749, 25.00700, 25.00646, 25.00585,
                         25.00518, 25.00444, 25.00362, 25.00272, 25.00171,
                         25.00060, 24.99938, 24.99802, 24.99652, 24.99486,
                         24.99302, 24.99099))

ggplot(data, aes(x = C, y = R, z = V)) + stat_contour(aes(color = ..level..))
```

This results in the following plot:

[image: Full plot]

My y-axis starts from (roughly) four instead of from one, like I would expect based on my data.  `ggplot2` is certainly capable of contouring this data:

```
data <- subset(data, R < 4)
ggplot(data, aes(x = C, y = R, z = V)) + stat_contour(aes(color = ..level..))
```

[image: Subset plot]

I'm not so concerned with the actual contours; I know that with the data range, it's entirely possible on plots like this that the whole missing region would just be blank based on the automatically calculated bin width.  My issue is that it becomes difficult to compare multiple versions of these plots when they all have differently-scaled axes.

I know I can force the axes to a certain fixed extent, which will certainly solve my problem.  I just want to understand the behavior of `ggplot2` in this case and why it decides to toss out this data.

Comment: I'm confused why you think that `ggplot` is "tossing data" when you explain fairly ably yourself that the placement of contour lines will depend on the resolution of binning (either `binwidth` or `bins`). Adjusting both of those shows more contours.

Comment: The problem you have is that there is very little resolution in your V, and thus ggplot deems it not worth plotting another contour line - the difference is too small. I'd add in a `+ ylim(c(0, 16))` or `bins = 50` or `binwidth = 0.0001` to the `geom_contour` call

Comment: The base and lattice contour methods allow you to specify the levels for contour lines. Is that what you are attempting to request?

Comment: @joran like I mentioned, I'm not concerned so much about the contours as much as I am that `ggplot2` is arbitrarily shrinking the domain of my input.  My data represents model data on a row-column grid, and the output plot implies that my model domain is much smaller than it actually is.  It seems to me that the default behavior of `ggplot2` (to truncate the plot to the extent of the contours) can more readily lead to misleading information than if the plot represented the actual extent of the contoured data.

Comment: I understand your concern. I think ggplot's default is misleading in your particular use case, but as a general rule it's probably appropriate. Imagine cases where you have 1-2 extremely outlying values. If you ask for contours, you are asking for a data summary and forcing the plot range to default to the maximum range of the data would likely make the plot useless in those cases. I think your best option is to simply specify the limits yourself (which can be done in a fairly automatic fashion).